# dart format --output=none --set-exit-if-changed

Tags: flutter, github

I got some assignment to do. I made a PR in GitHub then in `checks` I get this error. I am new to this issue. How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Run `dart format` on your code first and update your pull request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating a pull request is a simple as pushing a new commit from the same branch you originally made your pull request.

In your case, run the requested command, then add, commit and push:

```bash
cd /path/to/local/repository
dart format .
git add .
git commit -m "dart format"
git push
```

That will update the PR, and triggers its associated workflows (GitHub Actions).